# Using Visual Studio Designer how do I add an event (activated)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, events

I'm using visual studio 2015, I need to add a form.activated event?

I don't see any events in the properties window of the designer.

I know I can edit the form.designer.cs file directly, but the next time someone edits the design file with the designer that will lose the edit.

I have searched stackoverflow and can't find the answer, I know this is a stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just open the form in design view and click in the properties-window on the little flsh symbol. Double-click on `Activated` and the evnt with eventhandler is added.

Answer (score 1):

you can go on the Form.cs [Design] tab, then right click on your form, properties, click on the Event icon (the lightning strike) and you'll see a list of multiple events that you can add.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for the Form_Load event? if so just double click your form in the designer view and it will create the event for you, what ever you put in that event will happen everytime you open the form

Comment: No, I was looking for the activated event specifically.as I stated in the question.